# How to reset the calendar in wpf?

Tags: wpf, calendar

I am trying to set the calendar to its default (date of today) date. After changing it inside my program but lets say the user chose a date like 2 months backwards of forward, 
doing

```
 calendar.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;
```

doesn't help.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: i found calendar.DisplayDate = DateTime.Today;

Comment: so problem solved sorry for bothering

Comment: Check the Calendar.DisplayDate property. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.calendar.displaydate(v=VS.95).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found calendar.DisplayDate = DateTime.Today; 
solves it